# Swift CollectionView ReloadData changes order for a moment

Tags: ios, swift

I have a very simple CollectionView which shows 4 buttons, each with the name of the Turtles. When I click any button, I want to refresh my CollectionView in case my array has increased and a 5th name was added, which should then appear as a 5th button. This basically works, but the moment I press and release any button, the button titles show my array from the last to first and then switch back to first to last.

Does anyone know why it does that and how I can stop it?

I just want to update my CollectionView every time a button was pressed. If the array should increase, let's say "Splinter", I want the Button titles to stay the same on the first four buttons and just a 5th button to be added.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var meineCV: UICollectionView!
    let cv = CollectionViewCell()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cv.turtles.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        
        cell.meinButton.setTitle(cv.turtles[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        cell.meinButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        return cell
    }
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.currentTitle!)
        meineCV.reloadData()
    }
}
```

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var meinButton: UIButton!
    let turtles: [String] = ["Leonardo", "Donatello", "Michelangelo", "Raphael"]
}
```

Comment: Why is the `turtles` array inside `CollectionViewCell`?

Comment: yeah I knew that question would come up :) For this simple example, there is no particular reason why I did not put it in the ViewController. But I highly doubt that this is the reason why my button labels change from last->first and then immediately back to first->last after .reloadData() was triggered. Or is it?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong but it's just really weird to put the data source (`turtle`s) inside the cell. In each cell that you dequeue, they store `turtle`s... this is confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: I did not know that all of "turtle" is stored in every single cell. I just recently started with Swift :) Thank you aheze for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you see that the button labels are being changed at the moment of press gestures and you want to get rid of it.

Please try this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    let turtle = cv.turtles[indexPath.row]
    cell.meinButton.titleLabel?.text = turtle
    cell.meinButton.setTitle(turtle, for: .normal)
    cell.meinButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much for your help! I am still interested in why it changes the order when .reloaddata() is triggered. So if anyone has the answer, please let me know :)